# Authentication using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount doesn't return email for personal account

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount package to add authentication for MS accounts to my web application.
When I login using my work AzureAD details, it all works fine, returning the name and email claims as expected.
However, if I use the same code to login using my personal @outlook.com account, it still logs in fine, but does not return an email claim (just name, etc.)

Other posts I can find just seem to be about not including the correct scope, but I don't believe that this is the issue.  I am using the following code to initialise the authentication (note: User.Read scope is already added to Scope by default):

```
services.AddAuthentication(...)
                .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
                {
                    microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
                    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
                    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All");
                    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
                    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("email");
                    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
                });
```

What else should I be looking at, or is this simply how it works with personal accounts?

Comment: What claim, specifically, are you using to retrieve the email? (i.e. `ClaimTypes` member).

Comment: I am using ClaimTypes.Email, which is present when authenticating with my work AzureAD account, but is not there when authenticating with my @outlook.com account. Specifically, I use the following code: `var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();  var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);` in the authentication callback.  If I manually inspect all the claims returned, none of them are the email address.

Comment: Interesting. Well, "email" is the correct scope. It's documented in the Microsoft Graph docs, and of course, it's just part of OIDC in general. If the claim isn't there *at all*, then there must be some determination Microsoft Graph is making to exclude it. Maybe there's a privacy setting somewhere. Remember, scopes are a request, not a demand.